# Disappearing document title

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I am really new to using javascript and jquery in HTML so this is probably a really basic question but I am really struggling.

I have an HTML document with a header that I want to have disappear gradually as you start scrolling down. My current code looks a bit like this:

`document.getElementById("myTitle").style.opacity = (75-document.scrollTop)/75;`

I know the first part of the code works because I have set numerical values like "0.5" and "0.75" to it and it works fine but as soon as I add my janky formula it stops working.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The Issue:**

`document.scrollTop` will return `undefined`, as [`scrollTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop) is an *element* property.

[`document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document) is not an element, but rather an interface through which you can access them.

*<sub>(The document element would be [`document.documentElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/documentElement), but that won't work in this case as it refers to the `<html>` element. This element does not scroll and so its `scrollTop` value will never change.)</sub>*

---

**The Solution:**

The actual element that's scrolling is the `<body>`, and so you should reference that in your calculations instead.

Try replacing `document.scrollTop` with `document.body.scrollTop` as seen in the working example below.

```js
document.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  document.getElementById("myTitle").style.opacity = (75 - document.body.scrollTop) / 75;
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
}

#myTitle {
  padding: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="myTitle">
  THIS SHOULD FADE OUT
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery:

```
document.getElementById("myTitle").style.opacity = (75 - $(document).scrollTop()) / 75;
```

Notice, that whitespaces around minus are important!

Comment: not how jQuery scrollTop works. And if using jQuery why wouldn't you use `$(selector).css()`?

Comment: @charlietfl, what's wrong with my code? I'm using `scrollTop()` instead of `css()` because the OP wrote it in his/her code in the question

Comment: right...you fixed the missing `()` ... the css() would be for other side...`$('#myTitle').css('opacity',...`

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your opacity value every time user scrolls. Setting opacity value only once won't update it on scroll. You can use [scroll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll) event and every time user scrolls, set your opacity value based on current `window.scrollY` value (which obviously changes when user scrolls).

Learn about [events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events), they are really useful.